# MVP Passive View Model

Tags: mvp

Should models be shared between controllers, so that two controllers have the same model, or should they listen to an global eventbus to get notice when the model is changed?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with that?
normally, a controller should own all views, that are part of the same workflow. and when events by the system arise, the controllers should get noticed.
are we talking about a Application or? not a website?

Comment: I'm thinking about JavaScript application. Lets say its a simple address book, so I've one model that stores all the addresses. And I've several controllers for different parts of the screen (overview, edit mode, address count). Who owns the main address model and how all the other controllers get aware when the model changes? Maybe I've understood mvp wrong, but I thought there is only one view for every controller.